# create new unit test project never appears when creating a new project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mstest

Does anyone know why it happens?!

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

I choose mvc project, and when i click on the next dialog, I should have "choose unit test project" writing with a checkbox..but the whole thing is grayed out..why

I think the culprit is the registry, but i am not sure,,,

Here is the key in my regestry Editor undter testprojectTemplates:

```
AdditionalInfo http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=178318

Path CSharp\Test

Template  MvcWebApplicationTestProjectTemplatev3.01.cs.zip

TestFrameworkName  Visual Studio Unit Test
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and found your post here...

Which project template do you have selected? You can only create a unit test project with the wizard if you are selecting a template other than 'Empty' (e.g. 'Internet Application', 'Intranet Application', other installed templates):

[image: Screenshot of wizard...]